# Rails add hash into existing hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to do smth like:

```
a = Hash.new
a = {:profile => @user}
a[:profile][:contacts] = Hash.new
a[:profile][:contacts] = @user.contacts.all
```

but I am getting the error **can't write unknown attribute `contacts'**.

`@user` is the result of a `select` from our database.
I need to create a hash with this structure

```
[:profile][:name] = boris
[:profile][:sex] = 1
[:propfile][:contacts] = here anotrher hash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is convert to hash result after select from db using **@user.as_json**

```
  a = Hash.new
  a[:profile] = @user.as_json
  a[:profile][:contacts] = @user.contacts.all
```